Custom completer in node REPLServer withou losing built-in completions
I'm using the built in repl package in Node with a custom completer:
  const replServer = repl.start({
    completer: myCustomCompleterFunction,
  });

The purpose of the custom completer is to complete custom commands (that are added with replServer.defineCommand("myCommand", ...). For example, when I type
.myCommand foo

Tab completion should automatically complete "foo", assuming there's at least one item whose name starts with "foo".
I can make that work, but I want to fall back on the built-in completions, like completing variable names, when the input string does not start with ".myCommand".
Hence my custom complete function looks something like this:
  const completer = (line, callback) => {
    if (line.startsWith(".edit ")) {
      return editCompleter(line);
    }

    return defaultCompleter(line, callback);
  };

When the input text does not begin with one of my custom commands, I want the default behavior of the completer to kick in.
The problem is I can't find a way to get a reference to the default completer before it was replaced with my custom completer. I'm guessing not many people use the REPLServer class in userland, hence this use case has never really been supported. Is that the case, or is there some trick that I haven't figured out?

Theres no built in export of the default completer: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/41cb292778de65133d93a393853dc5caef2b8ee1/lib/repl.js#L786 Perhaps you can find away using it while browsing/studding the source code. Something like this repl.REPLServer.prototype.complete.bind(replServer) could give you access to the built in completer function. Not sure how to combine that with your custom function https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/41cb292778de65133d93a393853dc5caef2b8ee1/lib/repl.js#L1277 & https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/41cb292778de65133d93a393853dc5caef2b8ee1/lib/repl.js#L1321
